# C# Реализация интерфеса

Tags: c#

Пишу плагин для программы, появилась необходимость получить версию программы... У программы в API есть такой [интерфейс](https://iiko.github.io/front.api.sdk/v7/html/M_Resto_Front_Api_IPluginIntegrationService_GetApplicationVersion.htm#!) который как раз возвращает версию

```
namespace Resto.Front.Api
{
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Service provides integration features.
    public interface IPluginIntegrationService
    {
        //
        // Сводка:
        //     Gets version of the iikoFront application.
        //
        // Возврат:
        //     A string containing the application version.
        [NotNull]
        [PublicAPI]
        string GetApplicationVersion();
    }
}
```

Но как его правильно реализовать в своём классе для получения данных?

Так я создаю класс реализующий IPluginIntegrationService
а собственно где результат взять?(

```
public class Version : IPluginIntegrationService
{
    public string GetApplicationVersion()
    {
        return ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Создать или получить экземпляр класса, реализующего IPluginIntegrationService, и вызвать ему метод GetApplicationVersion() записав полученный результат в строку. Вам самим этот интерфейс реализовать не нужно.

Comment: @aepot я дополнила, вопрос. Не понимаю откуда сам результат выйдет(

Comment: Повторяю: Вам самим этот интерфейс реализовать не нужно.

Comment: @aepot Не совсем поняла, интерфейс нужно применить к классу в котором нужно будет реализовать методы интерфейса, в противном случае я получу ошибку "класс не реализует член интерфейса IPluginIntegrationService.GetApplicationVersion()"

Comment: @aepot а я все поняла) у апи есть готовый класс который реализован с применением этого интерфейса, спасибо =)